# npm install downloading extra dependencies in the parent folder of node_modules

Tags: npm, npm-install

I have a project structure like below

```
proj
|
|--- sub-proj1
|--- sub-proj2
|-----  ...
|
|-----  package.json
|--- sub-proj3
|--- package.json
|--- ...
```

Whenever I run npm-install command in sub-proj2, command run successfully, it creates the node_modues in sub-proj2 folder and download the dependencies in the node_modules, but along with creating node_modules it also downloads extra dependencies in the parent folder of node_modues(in the sub-proj2).

How can I avoid this downloading of extra dependencies in the parent folder of node_modues ?

Comment: what do you mean parent folder of node_modules? Are you referring to proj folder? Also can you clarify your project structure

Comment: parent folder mean, suppose I am running npm install in the sub-proj2 then It should download all the dependencies in the sub-proj2-> node_modules but it was downloading some dependencies in the sub-proj2 folder instead of downloading all the dependencies in the sub-proj2->node_mdoules.

Comment: Thanks @NathanWright for your help .. just reset cache folder path It worked :)

Comment: ok glad to hear you got it working!